# Can pre-build events affect the defines and the include paths of a Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, c-preprocessor, custom-build-step

Is it possible to modify the list of defines/include paths passed to the Visual Studio compiler from a pre-build step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I Could not find any information on this, I tend to think they cannot.